# Does employers usually pay for parking?

Tags: travel, commute

All the places that I've worked at are all in the suburbs, so their office usually have parking spaces on its premise for employees to park. I'm looking into moving to a new job in the big city, so parking is very limited on its office premise, so most likely I will need to park my car at paid street parking or facilities everyday near the office.

Does employers usually pay for parking when the office is located in a area where employees will need to park utilize paid parking on a daily basis?

Comment: "usually" may add your country. Never had a workplace with free parking. Reduced costs, but still to pay for it.

Comment: *Every* company I have worked for offers *free* parking on campus for its employees. Of course, if parking was full when you showed up, you have to figure out what to do next yourself. However, I have never heard of a company that paid parking fees if you parked in paid parking outside. As you can see, the answer to this question varies across the world, so you have to specify which "big city" you are talking about.

Comment: What is more common is for them to supplement public transportation.  Paid parking spots are typically limited to higher management.

Answer (score 5):

> Does employers usually pay for parking when the office is located in a
>   area where employees will need to park utilize paid parking on a daily
>   basis?

There is really no "usually" here.

Some employers will pay for parking, some will not. In my part of the world, many employers do not pay for parking, while some do. Some have parking "allowances" which subsidize part or all of the cost of parking.

It really depends on the local work customs, the size and type of the company, and the overall benefits package. So there's no "one size fits all" with this benefit.

Many employers that do pay for parking will boast of that "benefit" in their job postings or their company website. So look there first. If you don't find it there, you can always ask the recruiter, or HR about this benefit and all others.

Answer (score 0):

If your place of work is in a "big city", it would be quite unusual for your employer to offer to pay employees' car parking fees. On the contrary, depending on how well developed transportation infrastructure is in your area of the world, it would be quite unusual to even find that many employees use cars to commute to work in the first place.

Comment: Were I work right now, commuting by car would be sheer madness. Office is 100 metres from an underground station. Nearest car park is half an hour walk away.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'd have said that's creepy, we must work in exactly the same place, except of course that there are at least thousands upon tens of thousands of workplaces that fit that description :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal standard.

My wife worked for several companies of various sizes in Chicago. Some did nothing to compensate for transportation costs (parking, trains, buses, permits, etc.). Others had programs to either fully or partially subsidize those costs.

It's another benefit to ask about and weigh when making a decision on a final offer.